# Jersey Service Initialization with HIbernate default dataset

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jersey

I have a stack that consists of Hibernate, Spring, and Jersey.

While a great deal of things are RESTFUL, not everything in our application is (and cannot be, for various reasons. I realize I break REST best practices in places.)

I need to do two things and cannot figure out how to make both happen.

in my application-context.xml I have the following

```
  <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mystuff.model"/>
     <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">data.sql</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
```

This normally loads some hibernate data into the database for me.
However, I also need to initialize some in memory structures in the service.

The moment i try to have my service extend ServletContainer and override initiate despite a call to super.initiate()
or implement AbstractResourceModelListener and then provide onLoaded(AbstractResourceModelContext modelContext)
I am getting null pointers because my initial data provided by data.sql is not there.

How can I do this correctly so I both get my data.sql loaded and can execute a few statements when the service is loaded?

(If anyone is curious, yes the service is a @Singleton)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the right answer here, is to use @PostConstruct despite the warnings eclipse may give you about restrictions and libraries. I'm not sure why that warning appears, or why it proceeds to work anyways, but @PostConstruct is the way to go to not trash other loading in Spring.

(That said, if you aren't pinned in, doing the initialization outside and injecting it is more RESTFUL and better and not needing @Singleton, but I assume in both the question and answer that it isn't an option for you for whatever reason.)